# One Error Regarding Boolean Expressions

Tags: java, boolean

Beginner Java learner here. I am working on a project where I was given boolean expressions, and make a program based on them.
I managed to get 3/4 of them done but one of them I keep getting one error regarding the " ! "

```
public class Boolean2{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println( "Please enter in your 3 Numbers ");  
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
         boolean boolNum;
         boolNum = (b>a&&c!=15);
         System.out.println(" " +boolNum);
         boolNum = (a>b||b<c);
         System.out.println("  " +boolNum);
         boolNum = (a&& !a); // This is the problem line
         System.out.println("  " +boolNum);
         boolNum=  (b<c&&c<a||c==a+b);
         System.out.println("  " +boolNum);

                      }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Boolean2.java:16: error: bad operand type int for unary operator '!'
         boolNum = (a&& !a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, this `!a` would work, but Java is a bit stricter on it's types and won't allow `!an_int_var`. `!` only applies to boolean types.

And by the way: in C, `a && !a` is nonsense - it is always false since both sides can't be true.

Comment: The output of the 4 boolean expressions shown would be:
z = b > a && c != 15;                        true, false, neither  
z = a > b || b < c;                              true, false, neither
z = a && !a;                                      true, false, neither
z = b < c && c < a || c == a + b;     true, false, neither


That is what Im needed to do... Sorry, about my elementary knowledge. I was lucky to get that far on my own! :)

Comment: @GeorgeK - surely the result depends on the values of `a`, `b` and `c` that you input? If your question has been answered please accept an answer or else add more detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is an unary negation operator that expects a single boolean operand. Therefore it can't be applied on an `int`.
By doing:

```
boolNum = (a&& !a);
```

You are trying to apply `!` to `a` and `a` is an `int`.